# Converting hexadecimal to decimal gives unexpected result

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I am working with "Learn Python the Hard Way".

On Page 82 there is a `hexadecimal` encoded string.

```
rawBytes = b'\xe6\x96\x87\xe8\xa8\x80'
```

When I try to convert only one `hexadecimal` value to `decimal` value

```
int(0xxe6)
```

I get the error

> SyntaxError: invalid hexadecimal literal

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexadecimal values are composed of numbers 0-9 and/or A to F. You are using the letter 'x' twice in a row which causes the error. The escape sequence in the byte literal '\x' has the same meaning as '0x'. So try `int(0xe6)` and you are golden.